# VS Code not saving changes. MAC

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a folder with my VS code files saved on an external disk. When I connect it to my Mac I can see all of it. However, if I try to edit it I have the warning "Failed to save 'index.html': Insufficient permissions. Select 'Retry as Sudo' to retry as superuser".

When I retry as sudo I get the following message: "Error using --file-write: EPERM: operation not permitted"

I already tried changing the permissions for individual files, using the sudo command, even reinstalling PATH. However, I haven't been able to edit my code.

Any suggestions about it?

Comment: I'm the owner of the file. I already changed the permissions for all users by doing right click on the file and changing the privilege to "Read & write". I've also used sudo code and opened VS Code with sudo. But is not very effective to use that every time I'm opening a file.